# How can I save data in my session storage and get it later?

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect

I want to save data after clicking in a `<a>` (e. g: `<a class=".fach" onClick="reply_click(this.id)" id="deutsch" href="#"> Deutsch </a>`)
I gave every `<a>` a different id. The exact ids don't matter.
As well I added `onClick="reply_click(this.id)"` to later get the id by a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".fach").on("click", function() {
        function reply_click(clicked_id){
          sessionStorage.setItem('fach', clicked_id);
          $(clicked_id).toggleClass("open");
        }
      });
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
          $(".stufe").on("click", function() {
            var clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
            sessionStorage.setItem('stufe', clicked_id);
            $(clicked_id).toggleClass("open");
          });
        });
```

After saving it in my session storage I want to get it again and insert it into my redirection link:

```
var stufe = sessionStorage.getItem('stufe');
var fach = sessionStorage.getItem('fach');

    if(stufe != null){

        if(fach != null){

           window.location.replace('../learn/' + stufe + '/' + fach + '/');
        }
    }
```

As an addition, I want to clear the sessionStorage after a refresh:

```
function CallbackFunction(event) {
   if (window.event) {
       if (window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0) {
         sessionStorage.clear();
       } else{
         sessionStorage.clear();
         }
    } else{

    }
 }
```

When the class "open" is toggled for a certain `<a>` I want the background to become red:

```
#class-5 .open, #class-6 .open, #class-7 .open, #class-8 .open, #class-9 .open, #class-10 .open, #class-k1 .open, #class-k2 .open{
  background: #cb002d;
  color: white;
}
```

But strangely nonthing works. Were is my mistake?
If there is any information missing, please tell me.

Hope you can help me - Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a `click` event for your `a` tags, you can remove the `onClick` from the HTML:

```
<a class="fach" id="deutsch" href="#"> Deutsch </a>
```

and then, in your `click` event, you can directly get the `id` of the element that is clicked and save it to local storage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fach").on("click", function() {
      var clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
      sessionStorage.setItem('fach', clicked_id);
      $('#' + clicked_id).toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

**NOTE**: Do not use dots `.` in your HTML when you want to assign a class to an element. Use `class="fach"` instead of `class=".fach"`.

In case you want your element to toggle the `open` class, all you have to do is add a CSS rule for `open`:

```
.open{
  background: #cb002d;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is stufe ever not null? You shouldn't have two .ready functions. Just have one and call everything in it at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".fach").on("click", function() {
        function reply_click(clicked_id){
          sessionStorage.setItem('fach', clicked_id);
          $(clicked_id).toggleClass("open");
        }
      });
     $(".stufe").on("click", function() {
            var clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
            sessionStorage.setItem('stufe', clicked_id);
            $(clicked_id).toggleClass("open");
          });
        });
```

Also, a .toggleclass needs two classes:

```
.toggleclass('open','classWithRedBackground')
```

I don't see a class with a red background in your css
-its not being assigned
-it isn't defined anyway

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to add it. It is now added in my question.

Comment: But my redirection works now. The problem is: The background doesn't change when the class open is toggled.